# Working with Ctypes and replacing array values

Tags: python, ctypes

I am working on modifying a python wrapper using ctypes found here:
https://github.com/Grix/helios_dac/blob/master/sdk/examples/python/linux_example.py

I am using the logic of mutability and passing by reference of usual python code and the code no longer works if I change the lines 33 and 39:

```
for j, f in enumerate(frames[i]):
    if (j < 500):
        x = round(j * 0xFFF / 500)
    else:
        x = round(0xFFF - ((j - 500) * 0xFFF / 500))

    f = HeliosPoint(int(x),int(y),255,255,255,255)
```

Can someone explain why? Is f not equivalent to frames[i][j]?

Comment: In the last line, you only assign a new value to *f*, but that **doesn't change** *f*'s **old** value (`frames[i][j]`). Same thing as: `for item in [1, 2, 3]: item = 5`.

Comment: please answer so I can accept. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. I will, most likely tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

According to [[Python 3]: The for statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> The for-loop makes assignments to the variables(s) in the target list. This overwrites all previous assignments to those variables including those made in the suite of the for-loop:
>
> ```py
> for i in range(10):
>     print(i)
>     i = 5             # this will not affect the for-loop
>                       # because i will be overwritten with the next
>                       # index in the range
> ```

I'll present a simpler example, and then extend to yours.

> ```py
> >>> l = [1, 2, 3]
> >>> for i in l:
> ...     i += 5
> ...     print(i)
> ...
> 6
> 7
> 8
> >>> print(l)
> [1, 2, 3]
> ```

The same code but without the loop would be:

> ```py
> >>> i = l[0]
> >>> i += 5
> >>> print(i)
> 6
> >>> i = l[1]
> >>> i += 5
> >>> print(i)
> 7
> >>> i = l[2]
> >>> i += 5
> >>> print(i)
> 8
> >>> print(l)
> [1, 2, 3]
> ```

As seen, assigning another value to the looping variable, **doesn't change the original value**. This can be put even simpler:

> ```py
> >>> some_variable = 1
> >>> some_variable
> 1
> >>> some_other_variable = some_variable
> >>> some_other_variable  # Here it will have value 1
> 1
> >>> some_other_variable = 2  #  The value will change, but it won't affect `some_variable`
> >>> some_other_variable
> 2
> >>> some_variable  # Its value is unchanged
> 1
> ```

To change the values in the list while iterating, one way would be using *enumerate* (as you're already using it in your code):

> ```py
> >>> l
> [1, 2, 3]
> >>> for idx, elem in enumerate(l):
> ...     l[idx] = elem + 5
> ...
> >>> print(l)
> [6, 7, 8]
> ```

Applying the same principle to your problem: the last line in your snippet:

```py
f = HeliosPoint(int(x),int(y),255,255,255,255)
```

should become:

```py
frames[i][j] = HeliosPoint(int(x), int(y), 255, 255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: So, did this answer your question?